# Challenged by types

Tags: haskell, types

The problem:

Currently I have a type `WorkConfig`, which looks like this

```
data WorkConfig = PhaseZero_wc BuildConfig
                | PhaseOne_wc BuildConfig Filename (Maybe XMLFilepath)
                | PhaseTwo_wc String
                | SoulSucker_wc String
                | ImageInjector_wc String
                | ESX_wc String
                | XVA_wc String
                | VNX_wc String
                | HyperV_wc String
                | Finish_wc String
                    deriving Show
```

(I'm using `String` from PhaseTwo_wc on as a placeholder for what will actually be used)

I have a function `updateConfig` that takes a WorkConfig as one of it's parameters.

The problem is that I want to be able to enforce which constructor is used.
For example in the function `phaseOne` I want to be able to guarantee that when `updateConfig` is invoked, only the `PhaseTwo_wc` constructor can be used.

In order to use a type class for this enforcement, I would have to make separate data constructors, for example:

```
 data PhaseOne_wc = PhaseOne_wc  BuildConfig Filename (Maybe XMLFilepath)
```

If I go this route, I have another problem to solve. I have other data types that have `WorkConfig` as a value, what would I do to address this? For example,

```
type ConfigTracker = TMVar (Map CurrentPhase WorkConfig)
```

How can I use the type system for the enforcement I would like, while keeping in mind what I mentioned above?

ConfigTracker would have to be able to know which data type I wanted.

*** Clarification:
I'm looking to restrict which WorkConfig that updateConfig may take as a parameter.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean for a constructor to be "used" when `updateConfig` is invoked.  Are you looking to restrict what kind of `WorkConfig` can be passed *to* `updateConfig` as an argument?  Or guarantee that `updateConfig` *returns* a `WorkConfig` made from the appropriate constructor?

Comment: Maybe a typeclass would fit your needs better?

Comment: I've discussed why that would cause another problem. Sure maybe I can, but I need to address the problem that approach raises.

Comment: @Michael Litchard It doesn't seem like a problem though. Each case statement becomes part of the instance declaration... In general requiring a specific constructor is unsafe...

Comment: @Michael Litchard Or if the map needs to be able to hold different WorkConfigs, then use exisential types. In all honestly, at that point I'd just go back to crashing on a pattern failure.

Comment: @alternative I'm not sure what case statement you are referring to. The problem I am referring to concerns ConfigTracker, mentioned above.

Comment: @alternative thanks. I'm new to how to use those but now I have a direction to go in.

Comment: What's calling `updateConfig`?  You mentioned a `phaseOne` function; presumably there's also `phaseTwo` and so on.  Are those calling `updateConfig`?  It sounds like you want `updateConfig` to behave differently depending on who called it.

Comment: @Wyzard The only thing updateConfig does is add another key/value pair to ConfigTracker. The different behavior I guess would be that a the type for each key would differ.

Comment: @Wyzard That's correct, there would also be a function phaseTwo (and so on) calling updateConfig. In the case of phaseTwo I want to restrict the updateConfig's parameter to be SoulSucker_wc.

Comment: You can't make a function do different things (e.g. accept or reject an argument) depending on who called it.  Can't you just write `phaseOne` to ensure that it never *passes* the wrong kind of `WorkConfig` to `updateConfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more concrete and drive the discussion, how close does this GADT & Existential code get to what you want?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DeriveDataTypeable, ExistentialQuantification, ScopedTypeVariables, StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

data Phase0 deriving(Typeable)
data Phase1 deriving(Typeable)
data Phase2 deriving(Typeable)

data WC :: * -> * where
  Phase0_ :: Int -> WC Phase0
  Phase1_ :: Bool -> WC Phase1
 deriving (Typeable)
deriving instance Show (WC a)

data Some = forall a. Typeable a => Some (WC a)
deriving instance Show Some

things :: [Some]
things = [ Some (Phase0_ 6) , Some (Phase1_ True) ]

do'phase0 :: WC Phase0 -> WC Phase1
do'phase0 (Phase0_ i) = Phase1_ (even i)

-- Simplify by using TypeRep of the Phase* types as key
type M = Map.Map TypeRep Some

updateConfig :: forall a. Typeable a => WC a -> M -> M
updateConfig wc m = Map.insert key (Some wc) m
  where key = typeOf (undefined :: a)

getConfig :: forall a. Typeable a => M -> Maybe (WC a)
getConfig m = case Map.lookup key m of
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just (Some wc) -> cast wc
   where key = typeOf (undefined :: a)

-- Specialization of updateConfig restricted to taking Phase0
updateConfig_0 :: WC Phase0 -> M -> M
updateConfig_0 = updateConfig

-- Example of processing from Phase0 to Phase1
process_0_1 :: WC Phase0 -> WC Phase1
process_0_1 (Phase0_ i) = (Phase1_ (even i))

main = do
  print things
  let p0 = Phase0_ 6
      m1 = updateConfig p0 Map.empty
      m2 = updateConfig (process_0_1 p0) m1
  print m2
  print (getConfig m2 :: Maybe (WC Phase0))
  print (getConfig m2 :: Maybe (WC Phase1))
  print (getConfig m2 :: Maybe (WC Phase2))
```

Comment: This is pretty close. I think I can work with this to get what I want. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a little vague, so I will answer in the general.

If you have a type of the form:

```
data MyType a b c d e f g = C1 a b | C2 c | C3 e f g
```

... and you want some function `f` that works on all three constructors:

```
f :: MyType a b c d e f g -> ...
```

... but you want some function `g` that works on just the last constructor, then you have two choices.

The first option is to create a second type embedded within `C3`:

```
data SecondType e f g = C4 e f g
```

... and then embed that within the original `C3` constructor:

```
data MyType a b c d e f g = C1 a b | C2 c | C3 (SecondType e f g)
```

... and make `g` a function of `SecondType`:

```
g :: SecondType e f g -> ...
```

This only slightly complicates the code for `f` as you will have to first unpack `C3` to access the `C4` constructor.

The second solution is that you just make `g` a function of the values stored in the `C3` constructor:

```
g :: e -> f -> g -> ...
```

This requires no modification to `f` or the `MyType` type.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is more of an extended comment than an answer. I'm a little confused. It sounds like you have some functions like

```
phaseOne = ...
           ... (updateConfig ...) ...

phaseTwo = ...
           ... (updateConfig ...) ...
```

and you're trying to make sure that eg, inside the definition of `phaseOne`, this never appears:

```
phaseOne = ...
           ... (updateConfig $ PhaseTwo_wc ...) ...
```

But now I ask you: is `updateConfig` a pure (non-monadic) function? Because if it is, than `phaseOne` can easily be perfectly correct and still invoke `updateConfig` with a `PhaseTwo_wc`; ie it could just throw away the result (and even if it's monadic too):

```
phaseOne = ...
           ... (updateConfig $ PhaseTwo_wc ...) `seq` ...
```

In other words, I'm wondering if the constraint you're trying to enforce is really the actual property you are looking for?

But now, if we're thinking of monads, there is a common pattern that what you describe is *sort of* like: making "special" monads that limit the kind of actions that can be performed; eg

```
data PhaseOneMonad a = PhaseOnePure a | PhaseOneUpdate BuildConfig Filename (Maybe XMLFilepath) a

instance Monad PhaseOneMonad where ...
```

Is this maybe what you're getting at? Note also that `PhaseOneUpdate` doesn't take a `WorkConfig`; it just takes the constructor parameters it is interested in. This is another common pattern: you can't constrain which constructor is used, but you can just take the arguments directly.

Hm... still not sure though.